# Android to azure mobile service "cross-laptop" connection issues

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services

I created an android application which connects to a Windows Azure mobile service. I followed the steps as is from the tutorial on the Windows Azure site. I managed to connect to the same service in the tutorial app provided.

The problem is - if I deploy my own application from my laptop onto my Samsung Galaxy S2, it crashes when I start the activity that creates the connection to the Azure mobile service. 
HOWEVER, when I deploy the same app from a different laptop onto the same phone, it all works and I can successfully consume the mobile service.

So my question is: Is there anything that I might be overlooking when deploying from my laptop because a want to continue developing the application but at the moment I can't test anything.

Comment: What's the error you're getting when it crashes?